# Formula to translate xy movement with rotation

Tags: image, canvas, rotation, drag

i have a canvas element that i rotate with context.rotate();

when i drag around the image in the canvas if i rotated lets say 90 degrees, and i move to the left, the image moves down,

is there a formula in which i can apply a movement of 
for example 
x+5 y+2 * degrees

and i get the real movement i need to do to move the rotated canvas in the direction i want? I would like to apply it to this function which works but with the undesired efect of moving left and the image moving down `

```
vm.canvasMouseMove = function (event) {
        vm.delta = Date.now();
        if (vm.mouseisdown && vm.delta - vm.now > (1000 / 60) && (event.clientX > 0 && event.clientY > 0)) {
            vm.now = vm.delta
            vm.snapshot.mouse.x -= event.clientX;
            vm.snapshot.offsetSlider.value -= vm.snapshot.mouse.x;
            if (vm.snapshot.offsetSlider.value < -160) {
                vm.snapshot.offsetSlider.value = -160
            }
            else if (vm.snapshot.offsetSlider.value > 160) {
                vm.snapshot.offsetSlider.value = 160
            }

            vm.snapshot.mouse.y -= event.clientY;
            vm.snapshot.verticalOffsetSlider.value += vm.snapshot.mouse.y;
            if (vm.snapshot.verticalOffsetSlider.value < -120) {
                vm.snapshot.verticalOffsetSlider.value = -120
            }
            else if (vm.snapshot.verticalOffsetSlider.value > 120) {
                vm.snapshot.verticalOffsetSlider.value = 120
            }
            vm.snapshot.mouse.x = event.clientX;
            vm.snapshot.mouse.y = event.clientY;
        }
    };`
```

This draws

```
ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
ctx.rotate(vm.snapshot.rotationSlider.value * Math.PI / 180);
ctx.drawImage(image, vm.snapshot.offsetSlider.value - (canvas.width / 2), (vm.snapshot.verticalOffsetSlider.value * -1) - (canvas.height / 2), vm.scaledImageW * vm.snapshot.zoomSlider.value / 100, vm.scaledImageH * vm.snapshot.zoomSlider.value / 100);
ctx.rotate(-1 * vm.snapshot.rotationSlider.value * Math.PI / 180);
ctx.translate(-canvas.width / 2, -canvas.height / 2);
vm.donePicture = canvas.toDataURL();
```

Answer (score 0):

This made the trick, passing the offset to the translate method, then draw the image only taking into account the canvas half translation

```
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate((canvas.width / 2) + (vm.snapshot.offsetSlider.value), (canvas.height / 2) - vm.snapshot.verticalOffsetSlider.value);
    ctx.rotate(vm.snapshot.rotationSlider.value * Math.PI / 180);
    ctx.drawImage(vm.canvasImage, 0 - (canvas.width/2), 0 - (canvas.height/2), vm.scaledImageW * vm.snapshot.zoomSlider.value / 100, vm.scaledImageH * vm.snapshot.zoomSlider.value / 100);
    ctx.restore();
```